# Xamarin Forms Emulator not working after release

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I created an apk file and installed into my device. Afterwards, I try running my emulator on visual studio but it does not work anymore. It kept showing me errors. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       
Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void Xfx.Controls.Droid.Renderers.XfxCardViewRendererDroid::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer.add_LayoutChange(System.EventHandler`1<Android.Views.View/LayoutChangeEventArgs>)' in assembly: 'Xfx.Controls.Droid.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Void Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer::add_LayoutChange(System.EventHandler`1<Android.Views.View/LayoutChangeEventArgs>)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod(MethodReference reference)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.RunTask()
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute()  iSmart_ProductionApp.Android
```

Comment: Clean solution and rebuild.

Comment: Only android emulator right? and what does it have to do with `I created an apk file and installed` into my device